# linq insert not work

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        using (mesteriEntities myEntities = new mesteriEntities())
        {
            var usern = Session["New"];

            var UserID = (from Users in myEntities.Users
                          where Users.UserName == usern
                          select Users.UserID).SingleOrDefault();

            var cati = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

            Job newJob = new Job();
            newJob.categID = cati;
            newJob.userID = UserID;
            myEntities.AddToJobs(newJob);
        }
    }
}
```

When I select a combo it should add the value of combo and the userID in the Jobs table both INT values.
The variables "cati" and "userid" have values.

I don't know what I should change in order to make the insert work.

Comment: Are you ever persisting your changes?

Comment: Sorry is one of my first examples in LINQ not sure what you mean

Comment: Did you get any other insert to work ? What database are you using ?

Comment: @Teodor, they are asking if you have ever saved any entity to the DB with LINQ?

Comment: i found out the problem Manu answer me correct it was my fault because i didn't enabled insert in entity datasource. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `myEntities.SaveChanges()` after your `myEntities.AddToJobs(newJob)` call should work.
Here's the [relevant documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb336792.aspx).